# after resizing /var now Ubuntu has two /var?

Tags: directory, fstab, resize

I had my Linux directory on `vda` disk and as it is obvious , it had `/var` directory in `vda1` directory.

```
vda     252:0    0   50G  0 disk 
├─vda1  252:1    0 49.9G  0 part /
├─vda14 252:14   0    4M  0 part 
└─vda15 252:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
```

so I decided to expand `/var` in to separate directory and added `vdb` disk and made partition `vdb1` . after mapping `/dev/vdb1` to `/var`  in fstab and rebooting , Ubuntu still has a `/var` directory in `vda1` .

```
vda     252:0    0   50G  0 disk 
├─vda1  252:1    0 49.9G  0 part /
├─vda14 252:14   0    4M  0 part 
└─vda15 252:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
vdb     252:16   0  200G  0 disk 
└─vdb1  252:17   0  200G  0 part /var
```

Is this configuration correct? and is it normal still  have `/var` in `vda1` directory after resize .

Comment: `vda1` is a partition not a directory and `/var` is a directory not a drive.

Comment: Everything looks correct. The `/var` directory exists on `vda1` (but is empty). `vdb1` is mounted on top of the `/var` directory, which is indicated by the mountpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the extra space that might be already used by the contents of the old `/var` directory, if there are any, there is actually no other adverse effects for having the old `/var` on disk in addition to the new one. Since you have configured the `/var` directory on the new partition `vdb1` in the `fstab` file, only this one is going to be used by the system from now on after reboot ... the old one on `vda1` is not even accessible in this situation. Thus, your current configuration is normal from the scope of your Ubuntu system.

If, however, you need to access your old `/var` directory for any reason then you can do it by first creating a new mount point under your home directory like so:

```
mkdir ~/bindroot
```

Then, **bind mount** `/` to that mount point like so:

```
sudo mount --bind / ~/bindroot
```

And access your old `/var` directory under `~/bindroot/var`.